# whic Table contain currency decimal name in Microsoft Dynamic GP

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-gp, econnect

Which table currency decimal values contain.Please provide Microsoft dynamic gp table name.
By using this way we can set the Decimal values in GP Tools->setup->Financial->Multicurrency.

Answer (score 0):

look in the table   CM20200 for column DECPLCUR , it contains decimal places for a currency id

Answer (score 0):

```
USE TWO

SELECT * 
FROM sysobjects o, syscolumns c
WHERE o.id = c.id AND o.type = 'U' 
AND c.name = 'DECPLCUR'
ORDER BY o.name
```

The above sql script will give you all the tables that have the decimal places field in the 'TWO' test company database.